# Comparable (Rankable / Sortable) enums in Common Lisp

Tags: enums, common-lisp

I wonder if there's any trick or library to get rankable enums in Common Lisp.

In general I define a set of enums like this

```
(deftype weekdays()
    '(member :sunday :monday :tuesday :wednesday :thursday :friday :saturday))
```

Surely I can compare two variables for containing the same weekday, e.g. if both contain :wednesday.

But I want to compare two different weekdays like "Is :thursday later than :monday"? That brings me back to constants

```
(defconstant +sunday+ 0)
(defconstant +monday+ 1)
and so on...
```

but that seems to be bad style.

What is best practice for doing this?

Comment: An answer addresses this for enums in general but for days of the week it's worth considering how, say `weekday-<`, should work: it would be desirable for the function to be transitive (I.e. If `a<b` and `b<c` then `a<c`) but it would surely also be desirable that each day is less than the one before it. Sadly you can't have both and so your ordering may as well be arbitrary so you could just use `string<` or compare `a` to `b` as (< (sxhash a) (sxhash b))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define the elements in a separate list, you can just compare them by position:

```
(defparameter *days*
  '(:sunday :monday :tuesday :wednesday :thursday :friday :saturday)
  "Keywords indicating days of the week.")

(deftype day ()
  "Type representing days.  A day is an element of the list *DAYS*."
  `(member ,@*days*))

(defun day< (day1 day2)
  "Returns true if DAY1 is earlier in the week than DAY2, according to
the order specified in *DAYS*."
  (< (position day1 *days*)
     (position day2 *days*)))
```

```
(typep :monday 'day) ;=> T
(typep :fooday 'day) ;=> NIL

(day< :monday :friday) ;=> T
(day< :thursday :tuesday) ;=> NIL
```